# Use regex to replace underscore with dash in URLs of Wordpress blog

Tags: regex, .htaccess, wordpress

I have recently replaced all URLs of my Wordpress blog containing an underscore with a dash.

Example old URL:
/this_is_a_test

Example new URL:
/this-is-a-test

However, Google still indexes my wrong URLs using an underscore. Unfortunately this leads to 404 errors.

How can I fix this problem by setting up 301 redirects with a regular expression using the Redirection plugin in Wordpress?

The plugin offers me the following settings:[image: Redirection plugin settings]

Which regular expression do I need to use in order to properly turn all URLs with underscores in URLs with a dash?

Thank you.

Comment: If you didn't change the default behavior of Wordpress post slug making, then a `[\w_]+` will do the job. If source URL field is the one to which you write your expression, you should try based on your posts URL structure as defined in permalinks settings. You should look at the plugin documentations first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugin to use: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ (requires at least the following version: 3.2)

Add new redirection:

- Source URL: `^(.*)`
- Match: `URL and custom filter`
- Filter Name: `redirect_has_underscores`
- Matched Target: `[dashes]$1[/dashes]`

and add the filter:

```
add_filter( 'redirect_has_underscores', function ( $result, $url ) {
    return ( strpos( $url, '_' ) !== false );
}, 10, 2 );
```

The filter matches only those URLs that contain an underscore, so it will be absolutely required, otherwise it will be an infinite redirect.

I used these guides:

- https://redirection.me/support/matching-redirects/ (URL and custom filter)
- https://redirection.me/support/dynamic-urls/
- https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/